# How to get information about specific number from call_logs

Tags: android, calllog

I know that you can get all the latest call related info, but is there easy way to get information about specific number? I want to know if owner has called to this number more or any other related info (I prefer just the if user has called to this number before one) or do I have to really make function that searches through all numbers? Sadly google didn't help me with that too and I really dont want it to go through all the numbers - might take too long overall, what is bad.

For example if I want all, I can use code like that:

```
String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
            Uri callUri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
            Cursor cur = activity[0].getContentResolver().query(callUri, null, null, null, strOrder);
```

How could I make it into specific number?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code you are having problems with and why do you think it would take too long looping through the calls?  Have you tried it?

Comment: I dont have any codes but searching solutions. Maybe it wont take too long looping through, but there might be cases where he goes through maybe hundreds numbers and in this case it might affect a lot more. If I could how ever easily search and get only related specific answers, then it might make whole thing faster?

Comment: Here's a hint: [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/CursorLoader.html)

Comment: Well, I know I can get with Cursor all the calls, I added example into main post - but I still dont understand how can I get specific one...

Comment: Use the 4th parameter to create a selection clause. `CallLog.Calls.NUMBER = 12345`

Comment: Thanks, you are a savior! If you want, you can post ur last as answer and Ill mark it!